# Computer is always frozen while running massive Python programs

Tags: 16.04, python, asus

The machine:

- ASUS ROG STRIX X399-E GAMING ACPI BIOS Revision 1002
- CPU: AMD Ryzen Threadripper 2920X 12 core processor, clock: 4000MHz
- Memory: (Got by `free -h`) 125GB
  [image]
- vm.swappiness = 60 (Got by `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`)

There are three operating systems:

- Windows 10
- Ubuntu 18.04
- Ubuntu 16.04

When we are running some heavy Python code with Pandas in Ubuntu 16.04, the computer sometimes is broken. The machine is still running, but the warning message in the monitor is `no signal`

After broken, I tried to press Alt + F1-F12, but it does not respond.

We don't have Python installed in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. (We haven't tried to run the heavy Python code in Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.)

Does anyone have a similar situation or any ideas that could help us?

Comment: 1) Did you install that Python code in Windows 10? 2) If so, did it work without freezing? 3) Did you install that Python code in Ubuntu 18.04? 4) If so, did it work without freezing in Ubuntu 18.04? 5) More important than your CPU and motherboard is memory; how much memory is in this system? Please click [edit] and answer questions 1-5; please don't use Add Comments, but use [edit] instead.

Comment: Edit your question and show us `free -h` and `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Thanks for the data, however, I need to see the full `free -h` output. Please let me know when you have that. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Try this temporary tweak and see if it helps... in `terminal`, type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10`. Report back.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: If you've overclocked your CPU or RAM, reset it.

---

**Possible swap issues...**

Unless hibernating, excessive swap partition size.

Try this temporary tweak and see if it helps... in `terminal`, type `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10`

---

**Update your BIOS...**

Your current BIOS is 1002

BIOS 1203 from 11/1/2019 is available [here](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-X399-E-GAMING/HelpDesk_BIOS/). "Improve system performance".

- confirm correct download page and BIOS versions
- download the newer BIOS
- backup important files
- install newer BIOS

---

**Test your memory...**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. They still run some other program on Machine. Memory does not have any problem. We did the `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness=10`, But we need to back up the important files, before update the BIOS. We will test as soon as possible.

Comment: @WeijieSun  The vm.swappiness tweak is just temporary. It's just to give us some idea where the problem is. Run the command before the Python programs, or just after booting. It'll reset at reboot. If it helps, we'll take the next step with it. Report back later.

Comment: @WeijieSun Do you hibernate this computer? If not, why such a large swap partition?

Comment: @WeijieSun How do you know *"memory does not have any problem"*? You **are** freezing.

Comment: 1. We don't think **Possible swap issues...** solve the error, because it was still freeze after we set vm.swappiness=10. 
2. "memory does not have any problem", Because we did a **stress testing** with all CPU  is running 100% for entire hour. The machine still healthy, So I don't think it is the memory error.

Comment: @WeijieSun the vm.swappiness tweak was to try and determine if there was a swap related failure. Other than a grossly oversized swap partition, we didn't see any improvement. Stress testing won't exercise 128G RAM like a memtest will. Please consider running memtest. That leaves the BIOS update. Have you done that yet? You never answered if the CPU/MEM are overclocked, or why the swap partition is so large.